# print variable returned by server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm creating a node.js app.

I have a list with 4 types of movies (see below).

When I click one of these types I make a call to the server, then the server retrieves from a database the movies of that type and sends me back the result. 
On my client side I can correctly see the result the server has sent me but **I can't loop over the result** in order to print all the movies to the screen.

```
<ul>
  <li id="Animation">Animation</li>
  <li id="Action">Action</li>
  <li id="Comedy">Comedy</li>
  <li id="Drama">Drama</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<% movies.forEach(function(movie){ %>  // doesnt work 
    <li><%= movie.id %> - <%= movie.title %></li>
<% }) %>
</ul>

<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('li').click(function(){
    var movieType = $(this).attr('id');
    $.post('findMovies', { type: movieType}, function(data){
        console.log(data);  // I see the array correctly in browser's console
        var movies = data;
      });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking for help with: If `data` is an array, you could use: `data.forEach(function(movie) { console.log(movie)})`

Comment: @jfriend00 looks like a case of "what happens on the server/what happens on the client" confusion

Comment: can you show the result of `console.log(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loop inside your post callback function:

```
...
$.post('findMovies', { type: movieType}, function(data){
    data.forEach(function(movie){
        var li = $('<li/>')
            .text(movie.id + ' - ' + movie.title)
            .appendTo(ulRef);//assuming ulRef is a reference to the ul element above
    });
});
...
```

Your code doesn't work because

```
<% movies.forEach(function(movie){ %>  
    <li><%= movie.id %> - <%= movie.title %></li>
<% }) %>
```

is not reprocessed after "post" completes.